# SQLiteDataReader ничего не находит

Tags: c#, sqlite

Всем добра. Работаю с System.Data.SQLite в консольном приложении. Пытаюсь вывести данные из таблицы `[talks]`, но они не выводятся. Хотя просматривая через спец программу - значения имеются. Ошибок нет. Подскажите, в чём проблема.

Код:

```
        private static void Heart()
        {
            string word = Console.ReadLine();
            string wordsSql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS [talks](" +
                "[word] TEXT, " +
                "[answer] TEXT)";
            string searchWords = $"SELECT [answer] FROM [talks] WHERE [word] = '{word}'";
            using (SQLiteConnection connect = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source = "))
            {
                connect.Open();
                SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(wordsSql, connect);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                SQLiteDataReader readerWords = command.ExecuteReader();
                if (readerWords.HasRows)
                {
                    while (readerWords.Read())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(readerWords.Read());
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("afagba");
                }
                connect.Close();
                Heart();
            }
        }
```

Comment: А в таблице `[talks]` что-то есть?

Comment: @gil9red да. И `[word]` и `[answer]` имеют в себе значение

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка ужасная, но в коде имеется две переменных - wordsSql и searchSql. Дело в том, что вторая переменная(Где используется SELECT) никак не задействована в коде. Нужно заменить `SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(wordsSql, connect);` на `SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(searchSql, connect);`

Comment: А IDE или компилятор не отметили, что переменная не используется? :)

Comment: @gil9red изменений в цвете почти не было, вот и не заметил :)